# android pause and restart alarm manager in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

i create AlarmManager in my MainActivity like this

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TransactionService.class);
PendingIntent   pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,   notificationIntent, 0);
       mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 2000, pendingIntent);
```

I want for some condition to stop this alarm manager in a broadcast receiver. Below the code of the broadcast receiver(whatever it is).

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Intent notificationIntent;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
}
}
}
```

So how can i access this alarm manager and pause it into my broadcast receiver, and how can i restart it again ?

Comment: maybe you can use a service which runs for forever in the background. you can than using using any condtion stop and restart it..

Comment: if i stop the service in my broadcast receiver then the alarm manager must restart it after 2 seconds, so this is not a solution

Comment: since AlarmManager is not your property, but is the system service, you can't stop it. You can cancel the scheduled event only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Intent notificationIntent;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TransactionService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,   notificationIntent, 0);
         mgr.cancel(pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

You simply have to rebuild your PendingIntent and could pass it to the cancel()-method of the AlarmManager. The identification of your PendingIntent will be done by checking the id of your PendingIntent and if the containing Intent will meet the filterEquals()-requirements defined here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29

More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29

If you want to restart, you simply have to register to your PendingIntent again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pause a `AlarmManager` once it has started, instead you can cancel the alarm manager and restart it again when you want it.

You can cancel an Alarm event if you know the id that is given at the time of alarm registration.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TransactionService.class);
PendingIntent   pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,   notificationIntent, 0);

alarmManagerstop.cancel(pendingIntent);
```